# Difference between member and method

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am searching for a difference between member and method.....

Comment: To steal from my geometry teacher: "All methods are members.  Not all members are methods."

Answer (score 5):

A "class member" is basically anything that can be contained within a class object. A "method"  is a particular type of member, described by MSDN as such:

> Methods define the actions that a class can perform.

See [C#'s documentation on class members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173113%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for a good explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Member is a generic term that encompasses the following: Constructors, Methods, Properties, Fields, and Events.

A method is a function that is associated with an instance of a class or a static class.

Answer (score 3):

A member is just about everything that you can declare inside a class, a method is one possible member type.

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you meen but a member of a class could be an propertie, a method, a public variable, a static method, another class, ..

Answer (score 0):

A method is something you call to perform an action and maybe return some data.  The easiest way I'd say to identify a method is of course it has brackets at the end ...(..)

A member holds some sort of data, could be a value or reference type.